# Getting SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" even though I defined 1 SLF4J binding

Tags: slf4j

I am building a Java library and whenever I run the unit tests, I get the infamous message

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Of course, the [slf4j website mentioned](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) tells me to be sure to add exactly one and only one binding. I have specified the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.13</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I search the effective pom, I indeed can confirm that is the only logging framework referred to.

I tried removing the <scope>test</scope> line for the fun of it, but that did no good:

I have a basic log4j.properties file in my classpath

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=System.out
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.levelInBrackets=true
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: How are you running your tests?  The message indicates that that binding is not in the classpath when you are running.

Comment: Incidentally, this does not answer your question, but according to the manual, the `slf4j-simple` binding simply outputs everything to `System.err`.  So it has nothing to do with `log4j` and will ignore your `log4j.properties` file altogether.